# tomcat works but the site is not responding

Tags: linux, tomcat, server, centos, port

I installed the tomcat on the centos, I configured it in the following way under ssl:

```
  <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
           maxThreads="200" keystoreFile="/usr/key" keystorePass="somepass" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

After completing the command, I get the title page of tomcat but in the browser I do not receive an answer.

```
curl -g -6 -k "https://[::1]:8443/"
```

I tried to change firewall settings using commands:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=5000/tcp --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

At reload I received a "COMAND_FAILED" error, restarted firewalld and rebooted the system, but unfortunately it did not do anything.

Comment: why do you open port 5000 on the firewall when your connector is listening on port 8443 (default SSL port) ?

Comment: Use this command firewall-cmd —add-port=8443/tcp —permanent for open firewall for port 8443 and reload it